# What is the purpose of AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution() and when to use it?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I get why we use AsNoTracking() to increase performance on queries to aovid the overhead of tracking in entity framework, but I find kind of confusing the purpose of AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution().

Can someone explain it to me like if I were 5?

Comment: Read the documentation. I think it explains pretty well. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking